# XBAPs and MouseWheel events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xbap, hosted

I've got an XBAP hosted in FireFox, which works great.  However, I cannot detect MouseWheel events ever!  I'm guessing that FireFox is consuming them and not passing them down to the hosted app.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

don't know what's going on with your xbap,
just wanted to let you know that i have a xbap that works with mousewheel and firefox.
tested on vista sp1 32bit, firefox 3.x ( can't verify right now )
so ultimately, this is possible.

i use the standard MouseWheel event on FrameworkElement.

hope this helps